# compile c++ code using makefile dynamically

Tags: c++, makefile

It is about makefile and I wonder if makefile can compile cpp files dynamically.

Suppose I have main.cpp, a.cpp, b.cpp, and c.cpp files.(probably d.cpp, e.cpp and more can be added)

main.cpp file has main() function and a, b and c have their own functions.

Sometimes I only want to compile main.cpp, a.cpp and b.cpp files and link them.

But sometimes compile main.cpp, b.cpp and c.cpp files and link. 
No rules for what files I want to choose to compile.

What I think is like

make a b

make b c

make a c

or

make a b c

then only the file name specified can be compiled and link with main.cpp file.

Is there a good way for this to be done?

Thank you.

Comment: this sounds like an xy problem.  source files can't be arbitrarily combined into a working executable...so there's some structure to the combinations you will put together, and that structure will dictate what makes for a 'good' solution. [if I may hazard a guess]  You might find it more productive to state what you're trying to achieve, that this is a part of.

Comment: I agree with @lockcmpxchg8b. Explaining why you want to dynamically link different sets of files is probably going to get you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution: make variables that you can pass on the command line. They take precedence over the definitions in the Makefile.

```
$ cat Makefile
SRCS = $(filter-out main,$(patsubst %.cpp,%,$(wildcard *.cpp)))

main: main.o $(patsubst %,%.o,$(SRCS))
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f $(wildcard *.o) main
```

Then, if you want to link only `a` and `b`:

```
$ make SRCS="a b"
c++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
c++    -c -o a.o a.cpp
c++    -c -o b.o b.cpp
c++ -o main main.o a.o b.o
```

If you want to link only `c` and `d`:

```
$ make clean
rm -f a.o b.o main.o main
$ make SRCS="c d"
c++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
c++    -c -o c.o c.cpp
c++    -c -o d.o d.cpp
c++ -o main main.o c.o d.o
```

And the default:

```
$ make clean
rm -f c.o d.o main.o main
$ make
c++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
c++    -c -o a.o a.cpp
c++    -c -o b.o b.cpp
c++    -c -o c.o c.cpp
c++    -c -o d.o d.cpp
c++ -o main main.o a.o b.o c.o d.o
```

If the default does not make sense (e.g. because methods are defined in several source files), change the default value of `SRCS` in the Makefile:

```
SRCS = a b
```

Note: do not mix up make variables, which definition appears after the `make` command on the command line: `make ... VAR=VALUE ...` and the environment variables that you can pass to the `make` process: `VAR=VALUE make ...`. There are relations between the two but they are completely different things.